# Creating folder in window's Program Files using java

Tags: java

I am creating an installer for a standalone application, which requires to copy all its related folders under `C:\Program Files\Company\Product`.
I am using below code to achive this:

```
boolean files = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Product").mkdirs();
    if (files) {

            System.out.println("Multiple directories are created!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create multiple directories!");

    }
```

However , folders are not getting created surely because there is space in Program Files. How to get it done.? I do have admin rights to create folders in Program Files.

Comment: your file path is wrong : `C:\\Program Files\Company\Product`.

Comment: no its correct as \ is treated as a escape character

Comment: ok, how come you treat  file.mkdirs as boolean? I think i would just execute the `files.mkdirs();` and check if it was created by `public File[] listFiles()`

Comment: Can you upgrade to (or are you already using) Java 7 or 8?

Comment: mkdirs returns a boolean.

I am confused only by the fact that if file already exist and why is he createing dir should it be other way around, first creat directory then file

Comment: @ImAtWar: Program is running perfectly fine if I create it in folder with no spaces. like in `C:\Programos\company\product`

Comment: @mk08 what u r doing is if ur file exist then u create a new directory again so first check if dir exist or not , if it exist then create the file and then else crate dir and then make the file

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I have edited a code.

Comment: @Tunaki : Am on JDK 8

Comment: Then you should consider using the new NIO.2 API: [`Files.createFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) instead of the old `File` object

Comment: @Tunaki : Thanks for your suggestion. When I use this , I am getting AccessDeniedPermission in Windows7. Is it because some folders are read only to Java?

Comment: This is why it is a good idea to use NIO.2. `AccessDeniedPermission` is clearly more informative that "nothing happened but it didn't work". Try to run your program with elevated rights (in a administrator command prompt for example)

Comment: @Tunaki : Yes it did work. +1 for suggesting NIO.2 API.

Answer (score 2):

Program looks fine. It will work if you run in administrative mode. (For ex: Start -> Right click command prompt -> Run as administrator)

Comment: Yes it did work with Run As Administrator and using NIO.2 API for files.